# What's the default time_out limitation of ruby httpclient

Tags: ruby, httpclient

Recently, I met a trouble when I intended to upload a very large file by using ruby httpclient. I got error message:
HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired

I know I can set default value of receive_timeout, send_timeout, and connect_timeout like this:

```
client = HTTPClient.new
client.receive_timeout = 50000
```

However, I am really curious about the default value of timeout limitation.Is there anyone could tell me this?Thanks!

Comment: The default setting is `60`. I cannot support this with a code ref, but I remember seeing it in the source.

Comment: Turns out, it was the standard ruby HTTP class, not the HTTPClient In case you are interested: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http.rb, line 644

Comment: Thanks. If I have a file whose size is 121MB, and use httpclient default send_timeout which is 120s. Assume network speed in my environment is 1MB/s, can I upload it successfully? I am really interested it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value is 60 seconds, defined in [httpclient/session.rb](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/blob/ddd141b30848a8c4df2dfa84602f80b5b8a5f362/lib/httpclient/session.rb#L136). This is also the place where the default values of the other parameters are set. The client [forwards](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/blob/ddd141b30848a8c4df2dfa84602f80b5b8a5f362/lib/httpclient.rb#L335) it to the `HTTPClient::SessionManager`.

Comment: If I have a file whose size is 121MB, and use httpclient default send_timeout which is 120s. Assume network speed in my environment is 1MB/s, can I upload it successfully? I am really interested it.